# After moving the state from localstate to globalstate, all buttons get clicked at once. How to solve that?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, react-redux

I just moved localstate of toggle-button(on/off with images) to global-state which in my case was a moving from React to Redux. After that buttons started to get clicked at once, how can I make that click only one button reacts only at one button? [image]

I am attaching the picture of two different kind of buttons in my project. They work the same.. but now they trigger all of its kind buttons which is clearly bad 
In case, its a normal and simple code for toggle so its basically return !state in Redux

// buttonActions.js

```
export const toggle = () => {
    return {
        type: 'TOGGLE'
    };
};
```

// buttonReducer.js

```
const buttonReducer = (state = true, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'TOGGLE':
            return !state;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default buttonReducer;
```

// code of the component

```
const Islbutton = props => {
    const [role, setRole] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
       if (props.auth.user) { 
           setRole(props.auth.user.role);
       }
    }, []);

    const test = useSelector(state => state.button);

    const checkRole = (role) => {
        if (role === 'Menager' || role === 'Technolog') {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        };
    }

    const toggleImage = () => {
        if(checkRole(role)) {
            dispatch(toggle());
        };
    }

    const getImageName = () => test ? 'islOnn' : 'islOfff'

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    return(
        <div>
            <img style={islplace} src={test ? islon : isloff } alt="" 
 onClick={()=> toggleImage()} />      
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: You may wanna post some code, otherwise the question is really hard to answer!

Comment: I mean yeah, sure, gonna edit it in a second

Comment: Wouldn't that `useEffect` trigger constantly? Unless you're updating `props.auth.user` to be false, that `useEffect` would fire on every render, right?

Comment: Nahh, it doesnt trigger constantly, I have added the empty array of the end of it to make sure it will fire only once per loading the website. Second thing, the useEffect is just to tell the setRole what role it gets after logging in

Comment: From the code and the problem described, I don't see a single reason why all buttons would fire at once. Moreover, I don't see a button, just an image with an `onClick` handler